# os.listdir get files out of folders too

Tags: python, operating-system

So if you do os.listdir f.e.

> os.listdir("C:/Users/user/Desktop")

it prints out files but folders too
f.e.

> output: ["text.txt","folder"]

so how can you print out every file in the "folder" too because they arent printet out

Comment: Use `os.walk` instead.

Comment: @not_speshal is right.  You could also write a function that prints out the content of a directory, apply that function for each directory you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `os.walk`, it will give you much better way to track the file names and path as it traverse folders with any depth. Example ->

```py
import os
folder_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    print(path) # it will print current path
    print(subdirs) # it will print list of folder in that directory
    print(files) # It will print list of files in that directory
```